# Salesforce site domain change?

Tags: salesforce, subdomain, apex

I have a salesforce site with doamin as below :

http://loram-ipsum.na15.force.com

and after almost 2 year salesforce change without any notification as below so all my resource stop working b'coz of path.

http://loram-ipsum.na46.force.com

As per my knowledge "na15" stands for server location (north america 15).

Thanks.

Comment: whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this from happening in the future, consider implementing 'My Domain' (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=0).  This will allow you to have a specific domain without the specific server identifier in the address.